# read in a file from a local drive to google colab

Tags: python

how can I read in a file (or csv) from my local drive to google colab (not from Google drive)

I assumed this would work:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2
from tqdm import tqdm
DATADIR = "F:/Colab Notebooks/kagglecatsanddogs_3367a/PetImages"

CATEGORIES = ["Dog", "Cat"]

for category in CATEGORIES:  # do dogs and cats
    path = os.path.join(DATADIR,category)  # create path to dogs and cats
    for img in os.listdir(path):  # iterate over each image per dogs and cats
        img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img) ,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # convert to array
        plt.imshow(img_array, cmap='gray')  # graph it
        plt.show()  # display!
```

but I get this error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'F:/Colab Notebooks/kagglecatsanddogs_3367a/Dog'
```

EDIT:

the code above works when I run it on my local machine instead of Google Colab

Comment: Show us the code where you open that file. Also, that error means you are trying to open a file that does not exist.

Comment: The error message sais it `'F:/Colab Notebooks/kagglecatsanddogs_3367a/Dog'` does not exist. Are you missing an `s`, i.e. dogs?

Comment: if I was running it on my local machine, I believe this should work, I think the issue is that I'm running it on google colab

Comment: nope, not missing an "s" :) @AntonvBR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colab runs on cloud machines, which have their own drives and directories.
For a single or few sessions you can simply upload the files you want. Click the little arrow at the leftmost part of the screen, go to files and upload whatever you want.

If you don't want to upload the file each time, you can save it in your Google Drive and access it like this:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive', force_remount=True)
with open("/content/drive/My Drive/...", 'r') as f:
    data = ... (read the file here)
```

Comment: Yeah, I know, I was hoping I could avoid this and load the file directly from my local machine without uploading it to Google Drive

Comment: You can add it to the local files in a colab environment instead of loading it to your google drive. The only issue is that it would be removed once the environment is reset.